# Unable to set the highest resolution for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS desktop when connected through a VGA to HDMI adaptor to Android TV

Tags: display-resolution, hdtv

I have a desktop with **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** installed and recently tried to connect an **Android HDTV** to it using a VGA to HDMI adaptor as my desktop has only VGA output. However, the screen resolution is stuck at 1024x768 and the output of 'xrandr -q' does not show the highest resolution of 1920x1080 as well. This is the output of 'xrandr -q'

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      61.00* 
   800x600       61.00  
   640x480       60.00
```

I tried to manually set the resolution by adding a 'newmode' of 1920x1080 using xrandr and then applying the mode to the VGA output using the following commands -

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --addmode default "1920x1080_60.00"

xrandr --output default --mode "1920x1080_60.00"
```

But the last command sometimes fails with either the following error -

```
xrandr: screen cannot be larger than 1024x768 (desired size 1920x1080)
```

or this,

```
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

I guess that there is no problem with the adaptor as it works perfectly at full HD resolution (1920x1080) when I connect the TV from my Windows laptop.

I will be grateful if anyone can provide any support in this regard. It'll be great if I could use the large display from my Ubuntu desktop.

If it helps, here is the output of **sudo lshw** for the graphics controller

```
 *-display UNCLAIMED
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dfff
```

and this is the output of **"cat /var/log/gpu-manager.log"**

```
log_file: /var/log/gpu-manager.log
last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-was-loaded file
can't access /opt/amdgpu-pro/bin/amdgpu-pro-px
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.3.0-62-generic/updates/dkms
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/5.3.0-62-generic/updates/dkms
Is nvidia loaded? no
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? no
Is intel loaded? yes
Is radeon loaded? no
Is radeon blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu loaded? no
Is amdgpu blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu versioned? no
Is amdgpu pro stack? no
Is nouveau loaded? no
Is nouveau blacklisted? no
Is nvidia kernel module available? no
Is amdgpu kernel module available? no
Vendor/Device Id: 8086:152
BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
Is boot vga? yes
Error: can't access /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.0/driver
The device is not bound to any driver.
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Does it require offloading? no
last cards number = 1
Has amd? no
Has intel? yes
Has nvidia? no
How many cards? 1
Has the system changed? No
Single card detected
Nothing to do
```

Also please note that I have set **nomodeset** in the grub loader, otherwise when the Xserver starts, I see weird flickering colors.

Comment: Try lowering refresh rate from 60hz to 30hz. If that works start bumping it up to find the highest refresh rate that works.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just tried with 30hz and still throwing up the same error that screen cannot be larger than 1280x1024. :( I did some more search and found out that enabling nomodeset doest not allow the intel driver to load. Also just checked that without nomodeset it loads the i915 driver, but I get a continuously distorting, blurred and weird color changing desktop practically unable to use.

Comment: Sorry I missed the fact you are using `nomodeset` to override normal graphics. Perhaps creating a new question on the `i915` issue might kill two birds with one stone?

Comment: Yeah, I'll try that. Thanks very much.